# Get Value from column list inside dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I want to extract the `Value` where the the key inside the dictionary where `Name` =  `Title`.

column name: `title`

Input:

```
name     title
1        []  
2        []
3        [{'Field': '4', 'Name': 'Title', 'Value': '32ff5a'}]
4        [{'Field': '6', 'Name': 'Company', 'Value': 'XYZ'}, {'Field': '1', 'Name': 'Title', 'Value': '0ac3c3327'}]
```

Output:

```
name     title
1         
2        
3        32ff5a
4        0ac3c3327
```

I tried:

```
df.title = df['title'].apply(lambda x: x.get('Value')[0])
```

But I got an error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `apply` with `lambda` and a generator:

```
df['title'] = df['title'].apply(lambda x: next((y['Value'] for y in x if y['Name'] == 'Title'), ''))
```

---

```
>>> df
   name      title
0     1           
1     2           
2     3     32ff5a
3     4  0ac3c3327
>>>
```

**Edit:**

Use:

```
df['title'] = df['title'].apply(lambda x: next((y.get('Value', '') for y in x if y.get('Name') == 'Title'), ''))
```

Comment: I get the following error
`TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: @james Ah will edit

Comment: Your last change doesn't recognise if its an instance and populates the title column with blank `''`.
The values from the title are all hashcodes

Comment: @james Show me your actual example data points

Comment: When there are two: 
`[{'FieldID': '689b4d67', 'Name': 'Company', 'Value': 'Google'}, {'FieldID': '184c7f18', 'Name': 'Title', 'Value': '55483e93a673ca4391c691b7117caf3c'}]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237417/discussion-between-james-and-u12-forward).